# getting problem of escaping fgets in for loop

Tags: c

I did a simple C program that include for loop, and fgets to get name from the user input. But the problem is that when the user input the number of the employee its escape the name. I'm not sure where is the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (){

        int emp;
        int i;
        char name[60];
        int id;


        printf("Please enter the number of employee :");
        scanf("%d", &emp);

        for (i=1; i<emp; i++){
                    printf(" Employee %d : \n",i++);
                    printf("Enter an employee name:");
                    fgets(name, 60, stdin);
                    printf("\nID:");
                    scanf("%d", &id);

                    printf(" ------------------------------------- ");


        }



}
```

Comment: Are you typing `1` as the number of employees?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is user error. Do not hit enter after the number of employees. Do not hit enter after an ID unless it's the last employee. The code expects to read the next input immediately after each numerical input, so that's what the user should supply.

For example, say you have two employees, Jeff is employee 1 and Eric is employee 2. You should enter "2Jeff" followed by "1Eric". Since the code doesn't expect the input to be a line, the user should not enter a line in response.

For example:

> Please enter the number of employee :**2Jeff**
>    Employee 1 :
>   Enter an employee name:
>   ID:**1Eric**
>
> ---

User inputs are bolded. The software behaved precisely as expected.

However, to provide better user guidance, it might be more helpful to tell the user this. For example, "Please enter the number of employee :" makes the user think they should respond with a line. So the code should probably say something like "Please enter the number of employee followed by the first employee's name with no space in-between". Similarly, "ID:" should be changed to "ID, followed by the next employee's name (if any) with no space in-between".

That way the user knows what the code expects.

Comment: Me thinks David is have some fun here, suggesting to alter what the user should do to match what code expects. Although it is sadly true, users are often left to adapting to code - let us hope in this case, OP's code is not widely distributed and can be re-worked for a more natural I/O.  I did enjoy reading this "alternative" fix.  Reminds me of a [2010 movie quote](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086837/quotes/?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu) "Chandra: Whether we are based on carbon or silicon makes no fundamental difference. We should each be treated with appropriate respect."

Answer (score 3):

`fgets()` is reading the <kbd>Enter</kbd> , the left over `'\n'`, from the previous `scanf("%d", &emp);` [@xing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154236/getting-problem-of-escaping-fgets-in-for-loop/54154552#comment95139535_54154236).

`"%d"` only reads up to the last digit, it does not consume characters after the last digit.  Those characters, such as `'\n'`, remain in `stdin` for the next input operation, which happened to be `fgets()`.  So `fgets()` then reads that lone `'\n'` as a short line.

The following name is then attempted to be read with `scanf("%d", &id);`.

It is a mess to mix `scanf()` with `fgets()`.

---

Instead drop using `scanf()` and use `fgets()` for all user input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
  int emp;
  int i;
  char ibuffer[42];
  char name[60];
  int id;

  printf("Please enter the number of employee :");
  fgets(ibuffer, sizeof ibuffer, stdin);
  emp = atoi(ibuffer); 
  // For better error detection, check fgets return value and use strtol()

  for (i=1; i<emp; i++) {
    printf(" Employee %d : \n",i++);

    printf("Enter an employee name:");
    fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential \n

    printf("\nID:");
    fgets(ibuffer, sizeof ibuffer, stdin);
    id = atoi(ibuffer); 

    printf(" ------------------------------------- ");
    printf("\nID:%3d  employee name:<%s>\n", id, name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're mixing `fgets` and `scanf` calls.

The `%d` format specifier for `scanf` reads digits.  Anything after those digits, *including a newline*, gets left in the input buffer.  Then when `fgets` is called, it reads everything up to the next newline.  The next character in the buffer is a newline, so it immediately reads that.

Replace the `fgets` call with `scanf` to be consistent with the rest of the input:

```
scanf("%59s", name);
```

Comment: just an additional remark : _scanf_ reads a unique word, stopping on the first space etc, the name cannot be _john doe_